# how to extract colored region on image and warp into desired size in python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

[image]

I'm new to image processing and computer vision,

I have the above book cover with extra masked region (956 x 712),
I need an assistance to get the below image(407 X 569) using opencv.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! can you please add some attempted code in your post? With the current information we don't even know if you can run python.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact coordinates of the book you can just select the area of interest using the following code

I assume you already have your original image as `img` as numpy array.

```
result_image = img[y:y+h, x:x+w, ...]
```

where x, y, w, h are bounding box coordinates of the book in the image.

If you want to automatically find the book on the black background
you can convert the image to binary and find the biggest non-black section. Then get the coordinates of this area and crop it.

`img`
[image: img before]

```
# convert to binary
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# find the biggest non-black area
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(
    binary, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE
    )
c = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# get coordinates of the biggest area
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)

# crop it
result_image = img[y:y+h, x:x+w, ...]
```

`result_image`

[image: result]